# pip with default python version OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a script that uses `speedtest-cli`, I have installed the module with `pip install speedtest-cli`. If I run `pip install speedtest-cli` I get the following

```
Requirement already satisfied: speedtest-cli in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

If I try to use pip with the default python, as recommended by another answer here, like so `python -m pip install speedtest-cli` I get

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip
```

I figured that the pip is setup for one of the other versions of python but the only version of python in `/usr/local/bin` is python3 and in `/usr/bin` there is `python`, `python2.6`, and `python2.7` but I have tried defining each ones of those as the interpreter at the top of the file and none of them works, each producing giving the same import error on the `speedtest` module.

Which version of python is pip linked to then, or why is the installed module not importing?

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question. You might consider using `virtualenv`. It is a simpler way to manage version dependencies of this kind. I find it's often a bad idea to use the base Python install for anything other than what the OS already uses it for.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson I intend to set up `virtualenv` now but I'm still trying to figure out what went wrong and fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution was to completed a fresh start.

Remove all references to `easy_install`, `python`, and `pip` using the following;

```
rm -r easy_install*
rm -r pip*
rm -r python*
```

Then I used [this](http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/09/27/use-python-effectively-on-os-x) guide to properly install, setup, and configure python with HomeBrew, with pip and virtualenv installed.

The article is fairly lengthy so I'm not going to copy it all out here but here is an image snapshot in case the link goes dead.

[image]